# Can we keep the header and footer option checked?

Tags: html, css, printf, media-queries

Can we keep the headers and footers option checked always by our code in html file?
Like how we can set default size of the page by the following code

```
@page { 
size: portrait; 
margin: 5mm 5mm 10mm 5mm;
```

}

can we do the same for the option headers and footers.
PFA the screenshot for reference
[image]